# Excel Condional Formatting Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a simple formula that outputs as TRUE when I put it in a cell but when I put the exact same formula in a conditional format the highlight does not show up. There are no other rules being applied to this cell.

```
=OR(AND(OR(LEFT(I56,1)="U", RIGHT(I56,1)="U"), H$5="Total",H56>$F56), 
AND(OR(LEFT(I56,1)="U", RIGHT(I56,1)="U"), H$5="OC-Normalized",H56>$D56))

I71 = "U"  (TRUE),
H5 = "Total" (TRUE),
H71 = 90,
F71 = 30,
So H71 > F71  (TRUE)
```

I have about 170 rows and columns A thru AFG. The conditional is only being applied to the first column of data (column H) currently.

I cant figure out how to get the excel table posted here and I don't want to spend half an hour trying. Unless it really helps. The big question for me is WHY would this formula return TRUE in a cell and not in conditional format on the cell?

Returns TRUE but conditional formatting doesn't get applied to the cell. I have tested each individual part of the formula and they all of one of the OR sections returns TRUE.

Comment: be careful with relative and absolute cell references used in your formula. Are you sure the reference of cell `I56` is floating, i.e. if you drag the formula to the right or down the reference will shift accordingly. If you need to lock either the column or row position, you should use absolute or partial absolute reference. Same question for the rest of the relative cell references you used in the formula.

Comment: Blach! I figured it out. I wish the 10 "how to guides" I read mentioned that you have to use the first cells address in your range when applying formatting. Otherwise it gets wonky. Once I did that it all seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Blach! I figured it out. I wish the 10 "how to guides" I read mentioned that you have to use the first cells address in your range when applying formatting. Otherwise it gets wonky. Once I did that it all seems to work